# Get samples rom TF dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, dataset

I have a TF dataset

```
train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

And since my data is huge (100,000) I want to select only a subset of data to train on
So i need to create a new TF dataset from the old dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [tf.data.Dataset.shard](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shard).

> Creates a Dataset that includes only 1/num_shards of this dataset.
>
> shard is deterministic. The Dataset produced by A.shard(n, i) will
> contain all elements of A whose index mod n = i.

```py
A = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
B = A.shard(num_shards=3, index=0)
```

If you want 1/10 of your original `train_ds`:
`new_ds = train_ds.shard(num_shards=10, index=0)`

Comment: B will be of type tf dataset wich same shape we batch size ?

Comment: Yes, it should have the same shape with only exception being the number of samples in the dataset.